# how to implement searching list view in windows store app using c#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

Xaml code for listview is some thing like this. I populate Id,name and email in each item of the listview.Listview name is resultview.There is a textbox to search.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay,Source=PropertyChanged}"/>

<ListView Name="ResultsView" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Margin="0,65,4,0" SelectionChanged="ResultsView_SelectionChanged_1" ItemsSource="{Binding contacts}" Background="White" ItemClick="ResultsView_ItemClick" Loaded="ResultsView_Loaded">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate> 
        <TextBlock x:Name="st1" Text="{Binding id}" FontSize="28" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Black"/>                                        
        <TextBlock x:Name="st2" Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="22" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Black"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="st3" Text="{Binding email}" FontSize="22" Grid.Row="2" Foreground="Black"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This is the class

```
    public class Phone
    {
        public string mobile { get; set; }
        public string home { get; set; }
        public string office { get; set; }
    }

    public class Contact
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public Phone phone { get; set; }
    }


    public class RootObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
    }
```

The data context for Resultview is set as followed in my application.

```
var _Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
ResultsView.DataContext = _Data;
```

Now the thing i need is when the text in the textbox changes listview items should filter according to the name.

As you told i added this part. bt it shows errors.errors are in comment lines

```
public string SearchText
  {
      get
      {
       return SearchText;
      }
      set
      {
        if(SearchText == value)
        return;
        SearchText = value;
        Contacts.Clear();//Here it says contacts doesnt exists in the current context.
        foreach(var item in ResultsView.where(contact => contact.Name.Contains(SearchText)))//it shows windows.UI.XAML.Listview does not contaain definion for where
           {
           Contacts.Add(item);
           }
       }
    }
```

I am getting those two errors.And i am workin on windows store app not on windows phone.this is all what i have done. if it doesnot work out please provide me an alternate solution.
-Thanks

Comment: Currently, it is too vague what you require. What do you mean "search the list view". Do you mean that you want a set of results to be filtered based on the input? If so, create an ObservableCollection in your ViewModel. Create a text property. In the setter of the text property, modify the contents of the ObservableCollection. Make sure to set your binding trigger to update on source changed. Also, look into Reactive Extensions to help throttle the changes, otherwise you will have terrible performance.

Comment: Yes i want to filter listview items on input. But listview items are binded to a class Contact. Now i want to filter that binded listview. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

- A ViewModel (you should be using Mvvm)
- A CollectionViewSource
- A method of selecting what to filter by
- A method of filtering your data

Create a ViewModel. This is where your Contacts are. Create an `ObservableCollection<Contact> Contacts`. At initialization, fill this `ObservableCollection` as `you would like.` Save off a copy of the base list as `_baseContactList`;

In your View, create a CollectionViewSource as a StaticResource in your Page.Resources. Bind its contents to your Collection.

Set your ItemsSource of your List to the CVS.

Now, you need to create a method of determining what to sort. You may do something like bind a `ComboBox` to a `string` property in your ViewModel. The setter of that property will change the values of your backing `ObservableCollection` similar to this:

```
public string SearchText
{
    get
    {
        return _searchText;
    }
    set
    {
        if(_searchText == value)
            return;
        _searchText = value;
        Contacts.Clear();

        foreach(var item in _baseContactList.Where(contact => 
            contact.Name.Contains(_searchText))
        {
            Contacts.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Now, this is pretty horribly inefficient and may not be idea for you. Firstly, it clears the search after every change. You'll probably want to do something like throttling it with ReactiveExtensions so that it only refills half a second after the last keystroke. Secondly, you'll likely want to replace the condition (`contact.Name.Contains(_searchText)`) with your custom criteria, possibly including checking the email as well. You may also want to remove case sensitivity (by comparing the "`.ToLower()`" version of `Name` and `_searchText`, or whichever two you're comparing).

So, in order to make this happen, you'll need a TextBox which connects its current string to `SearchText`. Something like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The `Binding` statement targets the `SearchText` property, makes sure that any changes to the `TextBox` gets reflected in `SearchText` (via `Mode=TwoWay`) and then tells it to send the change every time the text changes (at each keystroke) by setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger`.

Some future work you may want to add would be to have the clearing and refilling be both throttled and asynchronous, along with using an `IncrementallyLoadingObservableCollection`. Using the incremental loader will actually make it so that you don't necessarily need to throttle as much, as it should only load about 5 at a time. You can look up guides for making one.

That should be it (aside from styling each item). Hope this gets you on your way!

Comment: Also, the binding for the TextBox.Texty should be tiggerd on PropertyChanged. Very important or you will not have live search.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder is correct. I now realize that I solved for sorting by a property as opposed to searching. I'll try and change it later (don't have time now unfortunately).

Comment: Thanks a lot.. if you can help it out by adding text box. As text in the text box changes listview items should also change..

Comment: Changed. Hope that helps

Comment: oops its not working.. alright i will mention in detail what i want. so that i can get some more help from you

Comment: Please go through the code. I edited it. Made note what i exactly want.

Comment: First of all, you used a `List` instead of an `ObservableCollection` like I specified. Fix that, then tell us if it works. Also, post your implementation of `TextBox_TextChanged_2` so that we can see that you're clearing it properly.

Comment: You put your Contacts in a `RootObject` class. Where did you put your `RootObject` instance? wherever you did, call `myRootObject.contacts` instead of my example of `Contacts`.

Comment: I think you understood what i want.. jst get it executed and paste the working code if u can do it.